# Oracle store procedure to retrieve dates ny passing column name as parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql

The below procedure returns thousands of lines by passing start date and end date. Added to that i need to add one parameter which should apply the start date and end date on different columns such as created date, planned date and end date which are available in result set.

For instance if i pass the value as (created date,'31/10/2020 00:00:00','01/11/2020 00:00:00'), the filter should be applied on created date column, if i pass (end,'31/10/2020 00:00:00','01/11/2020 00:00:00'), the filter should be applied on end date column.

How can i achieve this  ?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CVP_TEST(STARTDATE VARCHAR, ENDDATE VARCHAR) AS
  st_dt TIMESTAMP := TO_TIMESTAMP(STARTDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
  end_dt TIMESTAMP := TO_TIMESTAMP(ENDDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss');



  cursor cur1(start_time timestamp, end_time timestamp)
    is 




           SELECT
            A.LGST_GRP_CD ,

            (case when A.FRST_SHPG_LOC_CD like 'D%' then A.FRST_SHPG_LOC_CD
            when (A.FRST_SHPG_LOC_CD not like 'D%' and A.DMCL_CD is not null and length(dmcl_t.shpgloc_cd) <= 4) then dmcl_t.shpgloc_cd
            --when (A.FRST_SHPG_LOC_CD not like 'D%' and A.DMCL_CD is null and length(dom_carrier.shpgloc_cd) <= 4) then dom_carrier.shpgloc_cd 
            else A.FRST_SHPG_LOC_CD end) AS Dispatch_DC, 
            --ba_tmextra.FUN_GET_INT_DC(A.LD_LEG_ID) AS INT_DC,
            'XXX' AS INT_DC,

            A.CUR_OPTLSTAT_ID,

            --V.CUR_STAT_ID, 

            A.TRIP_ID AS TRIP_ID,
            A.LD_LEG_ID AS LOAD_ID,
            A.CARR_CD AS CARRIER_ID,      
            A.SRVC_CD   AS SERVICE_ID,
            A.EQMT_TYP          AS EQMT_TYP,
            A.STRD_DTT  AS START_DATE,    
            A.END_DTT AS END_DTT,
            A.CRTD_DTT AS CRTD_DTT,
            A.TRCTR_NUM as TRCTR_NUM,
            A.DRVR as DRVR,
            A.TRLR_NUM,
            A.FRST_SHPG_LOC_CD,
            A.LAST_SHPG_LOC_CD, 
            A.NUM_STOP  as NUM_STOP,

            --BA_TMEXTRA.FUN_GET_STOP_LOC(A.LD_LEG_ID, 0) STOP_LIST,
            'XXX' AS STOP_LIST,

            LD_MMO.PRTB_CTNT AS LD_COMMENTS,

            A.MILE_DIST          AS MILE_DIST,
            A.TOT_SCLD_WGT       AS TOTAL_WEIGHT,
            A.ELPD_HRS,
            CM.chrg_extl_code2 as chrg_extl_code2,
            (case when CM.chrg_extl_code2 =  'HAUL' then C.CHRG_CD else null end) as Haul_Charge_ID,
            (case when CM.chrg_extl_code2 =  'HAUL' then C.CHGD_UNIT_RATE  else null end) as Planned_Rate,
            (case when CM.chrg_extl_code2 =  'FUEL' then C.CHGD_UNIT_RATE  else null end) as Fuel_Planned_Rate,
            (case when CM.chrg_extl_code2 =  'FUEL' then C.CHRG_CD else null end) as Fuel_Surcharge_Type_ID,
            (case when CM.chrg_extl_code2 =  'STOP' then C.CHRG_CD else null end) as Stop_Off_Charge_ID,

            --C.CHRG_CD        AS CHRG_CD,
            --C.CHGD_UNIT_RATE AS PLANNED_RATE, 
            NVL(C.MNLY_OVRD_DLR,0) as CHRG_GRP_AMT
            FROM JDATM_PROD.LD_LEG_T A, JDATM_PROD.CHRG_DETL_T C, JDATM_PROD.IA_DIST_MSTRCHRG CM, 
            JDATM_PROD.DMCL_T, 
            --DMCL_T DOM_CARRIER, 
            --VCHR_AP_T V, 
            JDATM_PROD.MMO_T LD_MMO
            WHERE 1=1
            AND A.LD_LEG_ID = C.LD_LEG_ID
            AND C.CHRG_CD = CM.CHRG_CODE    
            AND C.CHRGDETL_TYP_ENU  = 1
            AND C.CHRG_LVL_ENU  != 7
            AND A.DMCL_CD=DMCL_T.DMCL_CD(+)
            --AND DOM_CARRIER.CARR_CD(+)=A.CARR_CD
            --AND V.VCHR_NUM (+) = C.VCHR_NUM_AP
            --AND V.CUR_STAT_ID (+) != 825
            and A.mmo_id = ld_mmo.mmo_id (+)
            AND A.TRIP_ID IS NULL
            --AND A.LD_LEG_ID = 1001038103
            AND A.RATG_VLID_YN = 'T'
            AND A.STRD_DTT BETWEEN   start_time and end_time;
           read_value cur1%ROWTYPE;

           BEGIN
           --dbms_output.put_line('Accepted:' || STARTDATE || ', ' || ENDDATE);
           --dbms_output.put_line('Assigned:' || st_dt || ', ' || end_dt);
  
  
           
          


END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OR condition as follows:

```
AND (
     (P_IN_COLUMN_NAME = 'created date' AND A.CREATED_DTT BETWEEN   start_time and end_time)
     OR
     (P_IN_COLUMN_NAME = 'planned date' AND A.PLANNED_DTT BETWEEN   start_time and end_time )
)
```